# Element search not allowed as child of element nav

Tags: html, validation, search

W3 validator says:

```
Element search not allowed as child of element nav in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

From line 38, column 12457; to line 38, column 12464

Contexts in which element search may be used:
    Where flow content is expected.
Content model for element nav:
    Flow content.
```

The current structure is (simplified):

```
html
--body
----header
------nav
--------ul
--------search
----------form
------------label
------------input
------------button
```

I already tried putting my search form inside of nav, div and even inside the last li of my menu. I get that validation error every time. What is going on here? Where shall I place the search element?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the relevant structure. We cannot determine what's wrong with your structure if you do not share it.

Comment: anyway I tried on [https://validator.w3.org/](https://validator.w3.org/) the snippets coming from [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/search](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/search) and [https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-search-element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-search-element) and it also says something similar blaming that `Element search not allowed as child of element body in this context`. I wanted just to add some clues.. I can't answer this question

Comment: I'm starting to get the impression that this is an error in the validator. But maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/search)

Comment: also see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/search#web_app_search)

Comment: Can you create a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen: I already read that. If it tells me something about my question, I'm too dumb to get it.

Comment: @LajosArpad I think the snippets from mozilla.org that Diego posted would suffice.

Comment: Good luck then!